# Define a \<name> and \end<name> pair directly rather than define an environment called <name>?

Tags: macros, environments

While defining an environment `<env>` also defines the `\<env>` and `\end<env>` declarations, what are the circumstances where defining those declarations directly (without defining an environment) is preferable?

I see the following use where `\proof` and `\endproof` are defined separately in [the `informs3` document class file](https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/Management-Science-template-1489419504967.zip):

```
%% Use for proper proofs that end with extra space (regardless of the use
%% or non-use of \qed (=the black box)
\def\proof#1{\Trivlist\item[\hspace*{1em}\hskip\labelsep{\it #1\enskip }]\ignorespaces}
\def\endproof{\endTrivlist\addvspace{0pt}}
```

Is there any reason not to do `\newenvironment{proof}[1]{...}{...}` instead?

Comment: I'm always amazed when journal styles reinvent the wheel, making it worse than the available models.

Comment: @egreg Totally.

Comment: There are pieces of code which you can use both in LaTeX as `\begin{envname}`..`\end{envname}` and, e.g., in plain-TeX (, where you neither have LaTeX 2e's `\newenvironment`-command nor have LaTeX 2e's environment-mechanism,)  as `\envname`..`\endenvname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\newenvironment` other than checking that the name is "safe" to define does nothing different to the `\def` forms that you show (apart from using `\long\def` unless the `*` form is used).

Especially in older code you will often see the lower level form, going back to when it could take several minutes to load a style file and not doing the checks in often used but unchanging definitions was a useful saving.

Comment: I realize I can actually do `\begin{proof}{Proof.} It's obvious. \end{proof}`.